# Case when TypeScript declaration file shipped with a library uses features from newer TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

As of TypeScript 2.0, it's preferred that libraries' authors ship `.d.ts` files alongside the library code, so when devs install that library via `npm`, then they get both the library code and the TS typings for it.

My question is: what in a case, when I use TS 2.0, and the typings written for library `foo-bar.js` use features from a newer TS version?

It's not currently a problem I guess, because the only stable 2.x version is 2.0. But imagine TS 2.2 get shipped with a new keyword/operator/type support and libraries' authors start using it in the `.d.ts` files they ship with their code. Would that prevent me from using these libraries unless I upgrade TS to the latest version in my own project (prevent = syntax errors in 3rd party `.d.ts` files during compilation)?

Comment: You can tell npm which version to install, so just take the version that uses a ts version that is same or lower than what you're using. It's not different than with other languages. If I'm not using java 8 I can not use libraries that written for java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good question and largely rests on how committed to forward compatibility the TS engineers are. In general, when writing a compiler engineers will strive for backwards compatibility, meaning that any old code will still be compilable by a new compiler. Similarly, in general older libraries can be linked to by newer versions of the compiler.

This is a general rule of thumb, but sometimes compiler authors will break compatibility for good (or bad) reasons.

As another general rule of thumb, however, forward compatibility is not a big concern. The reasoning is that if you are wanting to use code compiled (ie- .d.ts files) with a newer version of a compiler, you are expected to use the new version. This restriction is bad for users who want the freedom to mix and match any library they want, but is bad for compiler authors who want the freedom to use new features in their compiled code.

The TS engineers are in general quite thoughtful and are likely

So, this is a long way of answering your question that it's likely that you will need to upgrade your compiler in order to link to libraries compiled by that new compiler.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I was just curious what options I have in case I can't afford to upgrade TS, while some of my 3rd party dependencies decide to use the latest and greatest version of TS all the time (without increasing the major version of their code). I guess I'll need to rely on other devs being mindful about the TS audience they target. Will see how it goes. Thanks again.